# unable to create android apk in ionic 2

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am new in ionic and angular.when I am trying to build android apk using following command **ionic cordova build android**.but it will give an error **BUILD FAILED in 57s (node:9416) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.**.I am using windows 10 OS ,node version 8.9.4,ionic 2. Please help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Check the package.json file and check the android version ==> "cordova-android": "6.4.0", Now remove the Android platform with this command (ionic cordova platform rm android)and then add the platform with this command(ionic cordova platform add android@6.4.0). After that run this command (ionic cordova build android).
I have tried on my project and it works well.

Comment: Yes. I'm pretty sure Cordova Android 7.0.0 is not supported yet by Ionic.

Comment: i have done all this but still getting the error ,please help